# Python 2nd action not executing

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to python and learning by doing.
I have a small section of code that isn't behaving the way I'm expecting

```
    if op.type == 19:
      if op.param2 not in group1:
              cl.action1(op.param1,[op.param2])
              cl.action2(op.param1,[op.param3])
```

the first action 'action1' is completing, but the second action 'action2' isn't.
If I comment out the line containing 'action1' then 'action2' completes just fine.

Thanks for looking :)

Comment: I'm not a python expert, but isn't the indentation important? lines 3 and 4 are indented way more than they should be

Comment: yeah i think the copy and paste might have done that, line 3 works though